# Update column in Windows Phone database

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ to SQL in my application for Windows Phone. Now I need to update the columns of my database.

They are defined like following:

```
[Column]
public string COLUMNNAME
{
    get; set;
}
```

Now I need to do the following, because I need to store larger data in database:

```
[Column(DbType = "NTEXT")]
public string COLUMNNAME
{
    get; set;
}
```

Of course, old databases should work too. So I need to update my database with the DbUpdater. But I could not found any possibility to update the column type.

My update looks like following (DbVersion is a instance variable):

```
var dbUpdater = db.CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater();
if (dbUpdater.DatabaseSchemaVersion < DbVersion)
{
    if (dbUpdater.DatabaseSchemaVersion < 2)
    {
        // What to do here?
    }
}
```

I tried to change the attribute and add the UpdateCheck definition, but this does not work.

It would be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to add a new column

Comment: I added now a new column. Is it possible to transfer all datas of the old column to the new column without doing this in a foreach loop?